# JPQl having error in query

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

```
Query query=entityManager.createQuery("Select e from StudentQualification e where e.student=:id");
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="student_id")
    private Student student;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="qualification_type")
    private QualificationType qualificationType;
    @Column(name="obtain_marks")
    private Integer obtainMarks;
    @Column(name="total_marks")
    private Integer totalMarks;
    @Column(name="institute")
    private String institute;
    @Column(name="year_of_completion")
```

Error on query excution: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [com.autosoft.fortune.model.Student (n/a)]
    my query is above and after that my class attribute what should i do

Comment: i am also doing this"query.setParameter("id", studentId);" in my next line of code

Comment: "id" should be a Student object you pass in. Are you? Since you only quote the query and omit the setParameter call

Answer (score 1):

> > i am also doing this"query.setParameter("id", studentId);" in my next line of code

See that what your SQL is :

```
 Select e from StudentQualification e where e.student=:id"
                                            ^^^^^^^^^
```

e.student is of type Student `private Student student;` and not simple integer.

So supply student object with id populated to query instead of id.